# JAVA Socket send Images or Videostream or something else?

Tags: java, android, sockets, screensharing

I have made a client and a server application to screenshare my desktop to the client. I do this by screen capturing my desktop using the robot class, saving the image as a PNG, and then sending it to the client, which is then read and displayed on the client. This works, however, there is a 2-4 second lag time until the image is displayed. I would like to get it as efficient as possible, like Skype ScreenSharing (seems instantaneous). Is there a better way of going about this or is this as good as JAVA can get? I read something about video streams, but would this be faster or is there a better way than either of those?

Comment: Simply encoding and transmitting the PNG may account for quite a bit of the 2-4 second delay you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go with the `Robot` class, my suggestion will be not to save the image to file, keep it in memory as a `BufferedImage` or as a `byte[]`
Also, if you want to reduce the amount of data you send to the client you can compare successive images and send only the parts of the image that have changed.